# Compare strings of a list and a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, matrix

I want to compare substrings of a matrix and strings of a list.

```
l1=['phone','bag','name','after']
```

```
l2=[['phoneedjf','jshph o n ejsh','pho ne'],
['ffaf terekdl','a hf ter','fd af t e rls'],
['name s', 'ram es','her na me is'],
['ba gg in g','ba g pa ck','b a g'],
['bo ok s','sksjbooksjfl','b o o k kfs ifh']]
```

And this my code:

```
l3=list()
l3=l2
    
import numpy.core.defchararray as np_f
new_data = np_f.replace(l3, ' ', '')
print(new_data)

new_data=list(new_data)

output = []
for row in new_data:
    new_row = [any(value in l1 and ' ' not in element for value in element.split()) for element in row]
    output.append(new_row)
print(output)
```

And the output of this code is:

```
[[False, False, True], 
[False, False, False], 
[False, False, False], 
[False, False, True],
[False, False, False]]
```

Even I tried this code:

```
for i, value in enumerate(l3):
    print([any(x in element.split() for x in l3) for element in l1])
```

But the compiler return this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

And my desire output should be like this:

```
[[True, True, True], 
[True, False, True], 
[True, False, True], 
[True, True, True],
[False, False, False]]
```

As you see in the code, I have copied the matrix `l2` into `l3` and then deleted the spaces between characters in `l3` to find the strings of the list in the substrings of the matrix and check them.
How I can solve this problem to have the expected output?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: every element in `l1` should check by all element in `l2`? if this is correct so for which element you need compute `False` or `True`? why `after` check with second element?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But I couldn't understand your question. I'm writing a program in which I need to know if there is the intersection in the strings of the list and matrix and the spaces isn't important. @user1740577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compare_lists(l1, l2):
    l2 = [list(map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''), l)) for l in l2]
    out = list()
    for ele in l2:
        temp = []
        for l in ele:
            temp.append(any([x in l for x in l1]))
        out.append(temp)
    return out
```

This function fist removes the spaces in all the strings.

Thereafter it loops over each element in the list.
For one element it checks if one of the words from list is in  one of the strings. This create a 4x1 array with False or True. The sum of an array with False and True is larger than zero when at least one element is True.
After that it appends 1 or zero to the output list.

Hope this helps, please ask if it is not clear how the function works.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution helped me alot.